# Website information update system for independent uploads

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have developed a student portal website for my college using Joomla 2.5 and now I want some mechanism to regularly update information on it.

My problem is that there are many societies in my college that organize events frequently and it is next to impossible to get their information on time to be updated on the site.

Is there some way possible by which those people can independently upload their events on the site without the administrator's interference and also without messing up with other facilities of the back-end?

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a CMS is to make things like this easier.   As @emmanuel points out this is why there are extensions, you should use a calendaring extension.

In my experience one of the simplest things you can do if most people on your campus have Google accounts is to create a shared Google calendar that you give create access to for a representative of each club.  Then embed that calendar on your site with one of the extensions for that.  That way you don't have to deal with accounts on your site at all.  There are a lot of ways to make it more complicated (like let each club have their own calendar and then you make a master calendar) but I think that could end up being more of a headache.

The biggest problem with calendars is getting people to list their events, because it is work for them.   Sites with big empty calendars don't look very good. So you may want to make sure you have some events by finding out if there are some repeating events that you can set up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try jevents component: http://www.jevents.net/

You could grant permissions to your sub admin users and add / edit / delete their events from the front end without giving them access to the backend of your site.